# iTerm2 clear screen should not delete output of running command

Tags: iterm2, fish

When I used `command + k` the output of the actual running command was not cleared. Now with my new MacBook I don't know how to set this feature again. Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this behavior doesn't have anything to do with the Fish shell. It's a key shortcut built into Iterm2. Similar to how Command-, will open the Iterm2 preferences window. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85489/iterm2-disable-command-shortcuts for one explanation of how to disable it.

Comment: With what I need to replace it?

Comment: The stackexchange question I linked to shows how to configure iTerm2 to ignore that key. You could also, of course, configure it to perform some other action than clearing the screen.